# selective filling of arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

If a create a new array in javascript such as:

```
var arr=[];
```

Is there a method to add elements to this array at selected locations eg. I want to add elements at index 3,5,6,10 in the above created array. Rest of the locations are empty/ undefined.

If yes, are there any that problems could arise by using such an array?

Comment: You don't know the actual size of the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using an object in this case.

```
var arrayLikeObject = {};

arrayLikeObject[3] = "a";
arrayLikeObject[5] = "b";
...
```

You can use an array object as well, like this

```
var array = [];
```

but the problem is, you ll have the rest of the array elements as missing.

```
var array = [];
array[3] = "a";
array[5] = "b";
console.log(array);
# [ , , , 'a', , 'b' ]
```

You ll be able to iterate them with a regular for loop like this

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
   console.log(array[i]);
}
# undefined
# undefined
# undefined
# a
# undefined
# b
```

but, `Array.prototype.forEach`, `Array.prototype.map` etc will ignore the missing elements.

```
array.forEach(function(currentItem) {
    console.log(currentItem);
});
# a
# b
```